# how perform ProxyExchange post multipart request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

please i need help !

I have tried to redirect multipart request using ProxyExchange, and I don't succeed.

Has anyone done it before?

thank u in advance

```
 @PostMapping("/service")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> proxyPost(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy, @RequestHeader("authorization") String authorizationHeader,@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
        proxy.header("Authorization-getway",authorizationHeader);

        return proxy.uri(dzOptServiceUri.toString() + "/api/service/").post(response -> {
            return ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatusCode()) //
                    .headers(response.getHeaders()) //
                    .header("Authorization-getway", authorizationHeader) //
                    .body(response.getBody());

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution even if i don't know if it is the best solution

```
  @PostMapping("/service")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> proxyPost(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy,
                                            @ModelAttribute ServiceDto serviceDto,
                                            @RequestHeader("authorization") String authorizationHeader,
                                            @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file
                                           ) throws Exception {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        proxy.headers(headers);
        proxy.body(this.buildBody(file,serviceDto));
        proxy.header("Authorization-getway",authorizationHeader);
        return proxy.uri(dzOptServiceUri + "/api/service/").post(response ->
             ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatusCode()) //
                    .headers(response.getHeaders()) //
                    .body(response.getBody())
        );
    }

    private MultiValueMap<String, Object> buildBody(MultipartFile file,ServiceDto serviceDto) throws IOException {
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("libelle", serviceDto.getLibelle());
        body.add("definition", serviceDto.getDefinition());
        body.add("path", serviceDto.getPath());
        body.add("icone", serviceDto.getPath());

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        // Ajouter un fichier au corps de la requête
        body.add("file", new org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()) {
            @Override
            public String getFilename() {
                return "";
            }
        });

        return body;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).